# error in tf tutorial for diamondback

Tags: ros, tutorials, wiki, ros-diamondback, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that there is an error in the tf/Tutorials/writing a tf broadcaster wiki for diamondback, but I want to check before I edit the wiki.

Specifically, on the page:
[Writing a tf broadcaster](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

In the launch file there is a reference to a package that does not come up in rospack find (turtle_teleop) and also two broadcast nodes are started, whereas the subsequent notes suggest that only one should have been.  So the existing code is:

```
<launch> 
<include file="$(find turtle_teleop)/launch/turtle_keyboard.launch" />

<node pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster"
      args="/turtle1" name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" />
<node pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster"
      args="/turtle2" name="turtle2_tf_broadcaster" />

</launch>
```

I suggest this instead:

```
<launch>
<!-- Turtlesim Node-->
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>
<!-- Axes -->
<param name="scale_linear" value="2" type="double"/>
<param name="scale_angular" value="2" type="double"/>

<node pkg="learning_tf" type="broadcaster_tf"
      args="/turtle1" name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" />
<node pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster"
      args="/turtle2" name="turtle2_tf_broadcaster" />

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9490/error-in-tf-tutorial-for-diamondback/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on Melonee's comment that the tf tutorials have not been updated for diamondback, I implemented the changes on the wiki.
Thanks for the help to get it right.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-20**:
Thanks Dan.